# Maximizing text inside an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a function that takes all elements with class="maximize_size" and maximize its content (text) as large as possible inside each element.

I would be happy if I could do this with a css trick, but I didn't found how.

So, I'm trying to do it with javascript/jquery... and I stucked in a point:

```
$(".maximize_size").each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var content = element.contents();

    var raiseContent = $("<div></div>");
    content.wrap(raiseContent);

    var currentSize = 10;
    while (currentSize < 150) {
        raiseContent.css({"font-size": currentSize + "px"});
        console.log(raiseContent.height() + " : " + element.height());
        if (raiseContent.height() > element.height())
            break;
        currentSize++;
    }

    element.css({"font-size": currentSize + "px"});
    content.unwrap();
});
```

When I use *console.log(raiseContent.height())* it shows *always 0* !!!

[FIDDLE here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hfvvvuab/)

And for that reason my break-condition inside the while never occurs.

I would be happy if you could give me some direction.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Viewport Percentage Units. Have a look at this post where it is described pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19814948/2950479

Comment: `raiseContent` is an empty div, of course its height is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add an additional element.  Simply compare the container's `scrollHeight` to its `height()`:

```
$(".maximize_size").each(function(){
  var element = $(this),
      currentSize = 10;

  while (currentSize < 150) {
    element.css({"font-size": currentSize + "px"});
    if(element[0].scrollHeight > element.height()) {
      break;
    }
    currentSize++;
  }

  element.css({"font-size": currentSize +  "px"});
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uvLndu8/)

Answer (score 1):

I just modified your Js function as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hfvvvuab/7/)**

```
$(".maximize_size").each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var content=$(this).contents();
    content.wrap('<div class="wrapped"/>');
    var raiseContent=$(this).find('.wrapped');
    var currentSize = 10;
    while (currentSize < 150) {
        raiseContent.css({fontSize:currentSize});
        console.log(raiseContent.height() + " : " + element.height());
        if (raiseContent.height() > element.height())
            break;
        currentSize++;
    }
    element.css({fontSize:currentSize});
    content.unwrap();
});
```

Comment: You are incredible !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the height of the newly created div. Since you are checking on the height and the measurement is px.

```
raiseContent.css({"font-size": currentSize + "px", "height": currentSize + "px"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfvvvuab/3/

Comment: But, if I change to other font-family, give a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/hfvvvuab/4/